# Comments from end of line to beginning of new line, performance benefit?

Tags: asp.net, performance, razor, webforms, compilation

I've just opened an existing ASP.NET Webforms project and it is full of the following pattern:

```
...
    --%><tr class="trSpacer30"><td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td></tr><%--
    --%><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><%--
        --%><td><asp:Button ID="btn_Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel"OnClick="btnCancel_Click" /></td><%--
        --%><td>&nbsp;</td><%--
        --%><td><asp:Button ID="btn_Apply" runat="server" Text="Apply" OnClientClick="return validateAndGenerate();" /></td><%--
        --%><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table><br /></asp:Panel></ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel><%--
--%><div class="Hidden"><%--
    --%><asp:HiddenField ID="hfHasPreviousValues" runat="server" /><%--
    --%><uc1:ucSearch ID="popupSearch" runat="server" /><%--
    --%><div id="dataPopup_SelectPerson" class="ui-dialog"></div><%--
    --%><div id="dataPopup_ErrorOrWarning" class="ui-dialog"></div></div></asp:Content>
```

pay special attention to the `<%--` at the end of each line and the `--%>` at the beginning of each following line... 
I asked a colleague why on earth someone would do that, and he sighed that they tried to talk another colleague out of it, but that he had insisted that it was a big performance win or something like that... Is this some primitive form of manual minification or something?

Now this is a mess to maintain and I'm probably going to throw all of it out (I autoformat all the time and this "style" doesn't play well with the autoformatting..) Also I have no intentions of doing this when I add new lines of code and having these comments appear only sporadically is even worse than having them appear everywhere...

Should that colleague come to me to ask why I threw out the comments, I want to at least be able to understand why they were there before I threw them out *'because they gave me a headache'*

**TL;DR;** : WHY would someone use `<%--` at the end of each line and the `--%>` at the beginning of each following line in an .aspx file?

Comment: I *think* this was/is necessary to stop unwanted whitespace changing the generated html and layout - not sure hence the comment - but I recall having similar issues in the past.

Comment: @DaveParsons but it is outside the `td` so whitespace would not be an issue in the first place right? That said I can't think of anything as to why this would be used...

Comment: @VDWWD I don't think it would be an issue, perhaps there was a browser that treated white-space between `td`s as significant but, again, I'm basing this of very vague memories. I'm not a fan of redundant artifacts in code but I'm even less a fan of removing anything if I'm not sure of it's purpose or function without a test suite proving to me that I'm not causing any problems by deleting it.

Comment: and it's between table cells which is even weirder.

Comment: i just tried it and removed the comments and the spacing didn't change. do they appear outside of tables too?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry for choosing such a terrible excerpt, yes they appear throughout the entire page, between every end tag and beginning of the next tag... it's hideous. I'll try to update the question later!

Comment: I've updated the code excerpt, it's not between every tag as I said in previous comment, but from the end of every line. When there are more tags in one line. It's like he's commenting out whitespace from his code..